# Why does Typescript error when there is a top level const or let with the same name in many files with Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, constants, let

Why does declaring a `const` or a `let` at the top level result in the TS2451 error (see below)? I understand that in browsers all scripts share the top level scope but I'm writing for Node.js where all [modules are wrapped](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_the_module_wrapper).

- Is this error in this scenario relevant for Node.js?

  - If not can it be configured away / is config my problem?
- Why doesn't the same error occur for var?

  - Isn't the scope at the top level near identical for var, const and let?

**a.ts**:

```
let lme = 'A';
const cme = 'A';
var me = 'a';
```

**b.js**:

```
let lme = 'A';
const cme = 'A';
var me = 'a';
```

**tsconfig.json**:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "module": "commonjs",
        "target": "es6",
        "noImplicitAny": false,
        "sourceMap": false
    },
    "exclude": [
        "node_modules"
    ]
}
```

**Output**:

```
$ tsc
a.ts(3,5): error TS2451: Cannot redeclare block-scoped variable 'lme'.
a.ts(4,7): error TS2451: Cannot redeclare block-scoped variable 'cme'.
b.ts(3,5): error TS2451: Cannot redeclare block-scoped variable 'lme'.
b.ts(4,7): error TS2451: Cannot redeclare block-scoped variable 'cme'.
```

**Context**:

```
$ tsc --version
Version 1.8.10
$ node --version
v6.5.0
```

I originally came across this when trying to port multiple files from `.js` to `.ts`, which had `const fs = require('fs');`. I had assumed most basic things would just work between `ts` and `js` written for Node.js.

Comment: Do you have import statements in your `a.ts` and 'b.ts`? Otherwise it probably doesn't compile it as modules.

Comment: @NitzanTomer Nope, those are stripped down examples. I didn't know that there was different compiling for modules and er, isn't every file a module?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The compiler won't treat your `.ts` file as module unless there's a (**used**) import or export in the file.
Because of that it complains about re-redeclaration of the variables.

For example:

```
const A = 3;
```

Is compiled into

```
var A = 3;
```

While

```
import * as Utils from "./utils"

const A = 3 * Utils.A;
```

Is compiled into

```
"use strict";
var Utils = require("./utils");
var A = 3 * Utils.A;
```

Without an import/export the compiler just won't treat it as a module.

---

#### Edit

You can use the `require` syntax, you just need to reference the node definitions:

```
/// <reference path="./node.d.ts" />
const Utils = require("./utils")
```

Comment: Thanks, however this seems to mean that TS doesn't support `require` syntax, which means all files ported from `.js` to `.ts` need to have the `require` replaced with `import`. This seems bizarre since it gets complied into `require` anyway.

Comment: That's not correct, you can use `require`, check my revised answer

Comment: Ok yes `require` is supported (I'm using `typings install env~node --global --save`), but it won't cause TS to treat a file as a module, which is annoying.

Comment: What do you mean? If you use `const Utils = require("./utils")` it should compile your file as a module.

Comment: I'm seeing the same behavior, using `require` does *not* cause the file to be treated as a module. Adding an `export` to the file does turn it into a module, so that fixed it for me. Using typescript 2.0.2. I wonder if this depends on the typings you have for `require` because I'm just using `declare var require: any`